# DataTables() is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a problem using DataTables:

I have imported it using cdn:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

and I have a script to "DataTable" a :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTableUser').DataTable();
});
```

but I always get the following error:

> zone-evergreen.js:172 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

here's my html page:

```
<div style="margin-top: 30px" id="wrapper">
<div class="d-flex flex-column" id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="card shadow">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">

                    <div class="table-responsive table mt-2" id="dataTableUser" role="grid" aria-describedby="dataTable_info">
                        <table class="table dataTable my-0" id="dataTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Username</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>P.IVA</th>
                                    <th>C.Fiscale</th>
                                    <th>Approva</th>
                                    <th>Rifiuta</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
                                    <td><a href="/back/(secondRouter:back-profilo)?id={{ user.id_user }}">{{ user.user_name }}</a></td>
                                    <!-- <td><a (click)="navigate2()">{{ user.user_name }}</a></td> -->
                                    <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ user.vat }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ user.cod_fisc }}<br></td>
                                    <td><i style="margin-left: 15%" class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
                                    <td><i style="margin-left: 15%" class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Username</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>P.IVA</th>
                                    <th>C.Fiscale</th>
                                    <th>Approva</th>
                                    <th>Rifiuta</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What have you checked?  Browser console errors?  Browser network tab for errors.  Scripts in the correct order?  Have a go at making a snippet / jsfiddle / very simple page with nothing but a table + the js call.  Here's a jsfiddle with it working, taken from the [datatables] tag.  https://jsfiddle.net/dyhvaern/1/

Comment: @freedomn-m yes I have checked the console errors, I have updated my answer with code of the page where the datatable belongs

Comment: Check the **rendered** html very closely for all script includes.   Some frameworks "helpfully" include jquery for you, but at the bottom of the page.  So you add jquery+datatables at the top, then some other bit of code reloads jquery later on, overwriting your jquery and, importantly, datatables.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the id from your div instead of the id from your table.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable();
});
```